# "Request method 'POST' not supported" after put security annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

I have 2 controllers:

a)

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/portal/form.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional
public String form(final Message message, final Model model) {
    return "portal/form";
}
```

b)

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/portal/form.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("#message.id!=null ? hasPermission(#message, 'WRITE') : hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") 
public String form(@Valid final Message message, final Model model) {
    if (message.getId() == null) {
        someService.save(message);
        AclManager.create(message);
    } else {
        someService.update(message);
        AclManager.update(message);
    }
    return "redirect:result.html";
}
```

Before I put annotations of security in Controller "b" all was well.
Now when I go to the page of controller "a" and I fill out a form, click a button that causes the controller "b" and I get "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported".
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

**UPD**:I helped add to the login controller RequestMethod.POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to debug without your spring security configuration, but I'm guessing when you go to /portal/form.html spring redirects you to a login page using HTTP POST while your login page controller handler is only mapped to HTTP GET. Try mapping the login page handler to POST method.

Answer (score 2):

I also happened to run into your described symptoms when migrating my application's usage of Spring Security `3.2.0.RELEASE` from an XML-based configuration to the *JavaConfig*-based configuration.

In my particular case, the message cause of *`HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`* was Spring Security's **default activation of CSRF protection** when using *JavaConfig*-based configuration.

To remove this cause, one can:

- either update the application to follow Spring Security's CSRF protection mechanism
- or deactivate Spring Security's CSRF protection mechanism.

To deactivate the CSRF protection mechanism, in the `WebSecurityConfigurer` do something like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable() //FIXME
            .authorizeRequests() ....
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been banging my head over the same issue for the last one day.